# What are the cheapest sailing options to go from Harbour Island to Nassau?

Tags: budget, transportation, ferries, sea-travel, bahamas

Staying at Harbour Island for a week in July and want to know the prices to get to Nassau for a day whether it by seaplane or boat.  Which is cheapest?

Comment: Here on TSE we don't really do recommendations. We can however help you look for cheapest options. I therefore removed the last question from your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can fly from North Eleuthera with [Bahamas Air](https://bahamasair.com/) or [Pineapple Air](https://pineappleair.com/). Indicative price I found was $153.20 return. You will need to add on the cost of getting to North Eleuthera via water taxi though.

[Bahamas Ferries](http://bahamasferries.com/fares/) has ferry services that stop at Harbour Island, however it does not seem possible to do a round trip from Harbour Island to Nassau and back in the same day. They do have a day trip option the other way around (from Nassau to HI), but that's of no use to you.

I believe the flight is your cheapest option.